# Taking a complete dump of CVS repository

Tags: svn, cvs, dump, cvs2svn

I would like to take a dump of a CVS repository alone. Please suggest me if i can use cvs2svn tool to take a dump of whole CVS repository with complete History.

If i'm using cvs2svn, what steps should i follow?

Assuming if i have cvs2svn installed, 
cvs2svn --dumpfile=PROJECT.dump PATH/TO/CVS/REPOSITORY
Does this command help in taking a dump for whole repository with complete history of revision.

Note: Here i would like to take dump of CVS repo, i will be loading this repo in another CVS repos.

Kindly point me out if there is an existing topic of this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just for backup an entire CVS repository you can just `.zip` or `.tar.gz` your repository. It will preserve all revisions of the cvs cause as the_mandrill said, there's no database like svn. If you want to move this repository to another place then, just unzip it, delete `CVSROOT` directory and make cvs init on that directory. That's all!

Answer (score 1):

`cvs2svn` is only for migrating a CVS repository into SVN. It will take a complete dump of the whole CVS repository and will combine commits for individual files that happened at a similar time and with the same commit message.  These will become a single SVN revision. You won't be able to use it to move the CVS repository to another machine, only to migrate to SVN.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So, let's forget about cvs2svn usuage, I just need a complete dump of a cvs repository. how do i do that?

Comment: Just back up the repository directory on the server -- that's all that is needed.

Comment: Should i make it as Zip file or is there any tool to this?

Comment: It's just a directory of files with the same directory layout as the source. There's no database or anything that requires special synchronisation. Just copy the files, zip them, whatever you need.

Comment: Ok, i assume that the revisions are preserved for all files in the dump taken from cvs repo, correct?

Comment: There is no dump as such -- the CVS repository is just a list of files containing all the revisions, one for each source file.